# Cannot find the viminfo file to fix the E575 error Windows 10 WSL

Tags: viminfo, wsl

I have been using Vim/vi for a while but my computer ran out of space while writing a file and then this error appeared and continues to whenever I open or exit vi.

```
E575: viminfo: Illegal starting char in line: s/School_work/.../t1_plotter.com
E575: viminfo: Ilegal starting char in line: ^I*^I1569136185^I0
```

etc.

Other responses have informed me I need to delete the viminfo file. However, I cannot find it. I have looked in `/usr/share` where I find the vim directory which contains the vimrc, as well as `/mnt/c/Users/<Username>`. But so far nothing.

Comment: It should be in your home directory. `ls ~/.viminfo`

Comment: This did indeed reveal the .viminfo file location ```/home/<username2>/.viminfo``` I had scoured this directory before but it was all but empty, only now knowing the file was there did i use ```ls -a``` to show the hidden file, i also thought that i was looking for _viminfo as im on Windows but i guess because its a linux subsystem its a linux file. This directory <username2> may be the directory for the wsl i am using as upposed to my main computer directory.

Answer (score 0):

Launch vim and run

```
set viminfofile?
```

That should tell you the location. (The default is listed at `:help viminfo-file-name`.)

---

Based on some comments, it looks like the issue was trying to find `$HOME\_viminfo`, since the OP is on Windows, but they are in the linux subsystem and thus should actually look for `$HOME/.viminfo`.

Comment: Defaults are listed at `:help viminfo-file-name`.

Comment: @Ben So i launch vim or open a file with vi and type the command ```:set viminfofile?```  this gives  ```viminfofile= ```. 
As for the ```:help viminfofile``` it is written  ```string (default: "")```. 

The ```:help viminfo-file-name``` it tells me ```$HOME\_viminfo``` is the default name. Using powershell i identified $HOME is c:\Users\<username> but there is no file _viminfo here. It also suggests  ```$VIM\_viminfo``` the only folder i have found close to this is ```usr/share/vim```

Comment: @Ben doing this generates a new empty file, apparently ```/usr/share/vim_viminfo```, however i cannot find the file when searching the share folder